# image of set size/aspect ratio, thats also responsive

Tags: html, css, image

I am building a responsive website. On the homepage I have a number of articles whose thumbnails should be displayed at 230px * 115px at full size desktop output.  The article publishers will be uploading images of all sizes with no particular set aspect ratio.

I currently just have code to resize an image based on it's parent container. the width will be 100% of it's parent container and the height is automatic and will vary depending on which aspect ratio of the original image.

```
.img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto!important;
}
```

Is not really cutting the mustard.

My research suggest using a background img with background-size:cover. Is this a good way to go is it possible to center the cover horzontally and vertically? And work responsively?

Abit more direction would be great there are alot of articles our there but I can't find the exact answer to my needs.

update: @LGSon That's Great thankyou. It's the best solution I have tried so far.... I like the way the image is controlled within the div. Perfect. I guess the difference is now how to control the aspect ratio of the div. if i set the width to 50% the height it still fixed.

Comment: @LGSon - thank you - would you know how to also control the aspect ratio of the containing div?

Comment: To center the background image set to cover, just use `background-position: center center;`.

Comment: You mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/gr25f45c/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `<img>` rule is good, but you have to pack each `<img>` into another container that gets a percentage-based width and `height: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the image rule to, along with your other rules.

```
.img {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Will you know the dimensions of the image or are they unexpected?

The rule above is meant if you control the image and its accordance to your ratio in the design.

height is auto by default and adding !important to it does not make much of a difference.

Using a background image is a neat feature but cover will not do the job as expected. It covers the container with the images stretches or shrunk as needed to fill it entirely. Background images are also not recommended for performs reasons as they are loaded regardless of being displayed on the page or not as part of the css file, unless you load CSS files on demand with that request which is not necessary.

Hoep this helps, I will be glad to clarify.

I also disagree with the comment made about setting the parent container's height to auto as it does nothing. This is the default behaviour...

Comment: This doesn't do it if the height is to be fit, check dupe link and you'll see what I mean, and `contain` is the one to use for `background-image` neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 200%;
  height: auto!important;
  margin: -50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img class="img" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png">
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/82bub31g/1/)**

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but this kind of cuts out the middle of the image?